# Stylus - interpolation in a mixin

Tags: css, stylus

I have a mixin and I want to interpolate the values passed in, but I am getting an error.

```
positionModifier( key, x, y)
    &.{key}
        background-position: {x}px {y}px;
```

The error that I get is:

```
   351|         positionModifier( key, x, y)
   352|             &.{key}
   353|                 background-position: {x}px {y}px;
------------------------------------------------^
   354| 
   355| 
   356| //        positionModifier( recyclebin, 4, 86 );

expected ":", got "}"
```

The code that I'm trying to generate (as seen on 356) is:

```
&.recyclebin { background-position: 4px 86px; }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm coming from using sass for compiling css and thought I'd give stylus a try (this mixin works normally in sass).

SASS version:

```
    @mixin positionModifier( $key, $x, $y) {
        &.#{$key} {
            background-position: #{$x}px #{$y}px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of passing integer values to the mixin, accept the whole integer + unit. So it means instead of having 4, You can pass 4px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `{}` by `()`:

```
positionModifier( key, x, y)
  &.{key}
    background-position: (x)px (y)px;

body
  positionModifier('test', 10px,20px)
```